# Heap Free list entry CORRUPTED on W7

Tags: windbg, heap-corruption

I try to understand a reported heap corruption on W7 (32 bits process on 64 os)
ON XP [this link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1081496&seqNum=2) was usually enough to understand, but not on W7

I'm using:
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 X86

I have found corruption using

```
 !heap –s –v
```

And tries to inspect the reported corrupted block.
[image]

I can’t understand what is wrong with the Blink->Flink.
Has anyone any ideas what is wrong, or where to look !

The entire freelist for this heap (found from !heap -a is circular, is that correct ?

```
0:000> !list -x "dd" -a "L2"  -m 0n1000 9c6b7048 
9c6b7048  06ca7008 9bf0d010
06ca7008  99491ef8 9c6b7048
 <Cut Cut>
9c6b7048  06ca7008 9bf0d010
```

Updated:

I have checked in a test process where heap is reported OK, and yes the FreeList is circular, the last entry points to the start.
In the original dump, I have made a script to follow the FreeList and check for correct Blink, and they were all correct.  This makes the reported corruption even more mysterious.
Do you all trust the  !heap –s –v  ??

Comment: I'm starting to not trust even `!heap -s`. See my question on that at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444589/address-summary-and-heap-s-disagree-on-mem-leak/21450087?noredirect=1#comment32386278_21450087